# what is the complexity of the summation of n vs the collapsed version of the same series?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory

so the summation from n to k of n can be coded as

total = 0
for i in range(0,k):
total += i
return total

but that can also be simplified to

return (k*(k+1))/2

but is that really a faster way to compute the sum or is the computer just doing the same thing behind the scenes?

I timed it in c++ but I'd rather get a more theoretical answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is much faster to run through a collapsed version of a series compared to doing a for-loop. There are many reasons for this, but particularly, the time complexity of calculating the sum of a series through a loop is O(n), since we need to iteratively add each element of the series.

On the other hand, using the summation formula gives us a constant time complexity (i.e., O(1)). Imagine it like this, given a series from 1 to 1 million that needs its sum calculated, it would need to do 1 million * number of operations inside the loop. In this instance, the increment (+=) operator would need to

```
load the value
increment it by i
store the value in the variable
```

every time we do an iteration. On the other hand, the collapsed version would always perform consistently at the same time complexity as whether if you're calculating a series that's 10 elements or 10 billion elements long, the formula would be executed one time. It's constant, thus "constant time."

Comment: But since the collapsed version is doing multiplication, it’s just doing repeated addition behind the scenes, right?

Comment: Technically, yes. However, due to multiplication algorithms, such as through bit shift operations, the difference is not linear. Multiplication, while slower than addition, is not equal to adding a number by n times.